# Plotting like Excel

Tags: r, loops, plot

I had a vector like this :

```
x= c(0.542949849, 0.242292905, 0.163459552, 0.069668097, 0.042969073, 0.035829825)
```

and I want to plot `(x[i], x[i+1])`. Using Excel I got this : 
[image]

How can I get this graphic in R ? I tried this :

```
for(i in 1:5){
  plot(x[i], x[i+1])
  par(new = TRUE)
}
```

but it doesn't give the excepted result

Comment: `y <- c(NA, x); x <- c(x, NA); plot(x ~ y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions.

The first uses base R only.

```
x <- c(0.542949849, 0.242292905, 0.163459552, 0.069668097, 0.042969073, 0.035829825)

plot(range(x), range(x), type = "n")
for(i in seq_along(x)[-length(x)]){
    points(x[i], x[i+1])
}
```

The second uses package `tsDyn`.

```
tsDyn::autopairs(x, type = "points")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
plot(embed(rev(x), 2))
```

or

```
plot(embed(x, 2)[, 2:1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want but you have to add a few intermediate steps.

You need to put in a qualifier to force the array to be numeric. This is the equivalent of forcing the array to be an array of float values.  Otherwise all you get is integer values in your array.

You need to redefine the sub-components of x to 2 new vectors. Vector 'a' has an index of elements from 1 to 5 of the x array. It appears on the x-axis.  Vector 'b' has an index of elements from 2 to 6 of the x array. It appears on the y-axis. The first elements in vectors a and b index position 1 are equivalent to x[i],x[i+1] where i is 1.

You need to bind the 2 vectors together and then plot the result.

```
x <- as.numeric(c(0.542949849, 0.242292905, 0.163459552, 0.069668097, 0.042969073, 0.035829825))

a <- x[1:5]
b <- x[2:6]

c <- cbind(a,b)

plot(c)
```

and the result graph is as follows

[image: result]

Comment: *You need to put in a qualifier to force the array to be numeric*: no, `x` as defined in the question is of class `numeric`.